# Login to a website using python requests

Tags: python, post, authentication, python-requests

I encounter some  difficulties to log on a website from a python script, in order to retrieve data from it later on, once I will be connected.
 I think that the part of the HTML page with the form expecting username and password is the following :

```html
<div class="contentLogin">
        <form action="/login/loginSubmit" method="post" class="memberLogin">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" >
        <tr>
            <td><label class="color2">Déjà membre</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="pseudo" class="input" name="login" id="login" /></td>
            <td><input type="password" value="pass" class="input" name="pass" id="pass" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="ok" class="color2 loginSubmit" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td colspan="2" >
                <a href="#" class="forgotPassword color2" id="forgotPassword">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>    </div>
```

I would like to use the "requests" module of python langage, to do the POST request that will connect me to the site.
 My code already contains the following commands :

```
import requests
pars = {'login': 'dva2tlse', 'pass': 'VeryStrong', 'action': 'Idunno'}
resp = requests.post("http://www.example.com", params=pars)
```

But it seems not to work, because I even do not know WHICH action should be indicated within th POST request. (I do not even know how exactly to use it, since I never done it)
 Thank' you to help me make all that work correctly,
David

Comment: If @Jivan's answer has already helped you resolve your question. You should accept the answer. The extended question has already been asked in another post.

Answer (score 3):

Change the url value in `requests.post` to match the one given in `<form action>` attribute.

Also, remove the `action` key in your `pars` dictionary.

```
pars = { 'login': 'dva2tlse', 'pass': 'VeryStrong' }
resp = requests.post("http://example.com/login/loginSubmit", params=pars)
```

If you want to keep your login state for further page calls, you can use `requests.Session()`

```
s = requests.Session()
pars = { 'login': 'dva2tlse', 'pass': 'VeryStrong' }
resp = s.post("http://example.com/login/loginSubmit", params=pars)
```

As long as you keep using `s`, you will stay logged in.

Comment: It seems to work, but I cannot even be sure of it; I do actually receive the "200" status code, but I don't know if it means that the POST request completed well.

Comment: @dva2tlse Why are you not sure?

Comment: There is another page named http://example.com/friends that I dunno whether it reaches it once logged

Comment: @dva2tlse ok you have to use `requests.Session()` for that

Comment: Thanks, the syntax of YOUR dictionary is the good one; it works fine now.