# Login to a website using python requests (cont')

Tags: python, http-post

I have already posted a question here on S/O, and the responses that I obtained helped me to make a great step forward, so here I am again. (it was on [Login to a website using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690808/login-to-a-website-using-python-requests); shoud I "answer" to this post, in order to ask this complementary question, or should I "ask" a completely new question, like here ?)(I could then delete this one)

I encounter some  difficulties to log on a website from a python script, in order to retrieve data from it later on, once I will be connected.
 It looks like my code does successfully pass the identification phase of the logon, by the following POST request :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import requests
password = 'VeryStrong'
sess = requests.Session()
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
pars11 = { 'login': 'dva2tlse', 'pass': password }
url11 = "http://www.example.com/login/loginSubmit"
resp11 = sess.post(url11, data=pars11) # Sends a POST request. Returns Response object
```

Then I record a file containing the reponse that I received :

```
Fichier = open('resp11.html', 'w')
Fichier.write(resp11.content)
Fichier.close()
print '\n\t\tOk, resp11.url='+resp11.url+', resp11.status_code=%i' % (resp11.status_code)
# Ok, resp11.url=http://www.example.com/home, resp11.status_code=200
print '\n\t\tfirefox -P def2 -no-remote resp11.html &\n' # to inspect the first recorded page
```

The contents of this file, seen with any navigator, show personnal information that proves a successfull logon.

Then I try a "user" page and inspect the reponse that I received :

```
url12 = "http://www.example.com/friends"
resp12 = sess.get(url12)
Fichier = open('resp12.html', 'w')
Fichier.write(resp12.content)
Fichier.close()
print '\n\t\tOk, resp12.url='+resp12.url+', resp12.status_code=%i' % (resp12.status_code)
# Ok, resp12.url=http://www.example.com/home, resp12.status_code=200
print '\n\t\tfirefox -P def2 -no-remote resp12.html &\n' # to inspect the second recorded page
```

This second page, once logged on, shoumd show a "user" page, but it only shows the same "/home" page, as before.
What can I do with that ?
 David

Comment: are you sure you're logged in with the session you use?

Comment: yes I am; because the site tells me how many "credits" I have left, a kind of money for certain operations. So I know that I'm logged to MY account.

Comment: good. then discarding all the **Fichier** stuff, can you verify that `sess.get('home_url')` the response and content also prove you're still logged in with the session?

Comment: I'll check that now...

Comment: Also, please post your response headers, as status_code = 200 isn't really helpful for understanding the issue

Comment: well, it seems that I am still logged in, since the "credits" say so; but here is almost nothing else on the page.

Comment: here comes the headers, one minute...

Comment: CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-language': 'fr', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'set-cookie': 'dating_comfrom=1; expires=Wed, 01-Apr-2015 15:52:54 GMT; path=/, dating_cf0=deleted; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2014 16:52:54 GMT; path=/, dating_cf1=S236; expires=Wed, 01-Apr-2015 15:52:54 GMT; path=/, dating_cf2=deleted; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2014 16:52:54 GMT; path=/, dating_cfsa0=deleted; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2014 16:52:54 GMT; path=/, dating_cfsa1=deleted; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2014 16:52:54 GMT; path=/, dating_cfsa2=deleted; expires=Wed, 01-Jan-2014 16:52:54 GMT; 
too long; chat ? I don't know how.

Comment: path=/', 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'vary': 'Host', 'server': 'Apache', 'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'x-ua-compatible': 'requiresActiveX=true', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'x-from': 'eden-http4', 'date': 'Thu, 01 Jan 2015 16:52:54 GMT', 'p3p': 'policyref="/p3p.xml",CP="NON DSP COR CURa PSA PSD OUR BUS NAV STA"', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})

Comment: anyway, I do not yet have enough reputation to chat ! I hope that these headers will tell you what happens; thanks

Comment: Don't worry, is the response headers from `/home`?

Comment: I don't really understand the question; what do you mean by "from /home" ?

Comment: anyway it seems that the site uses some sort of cookies. Can you try sending the cookies along with your requests? like: after logged in, get the cookies by `cookies=resp11.cookies`, then do the new get to `/friend` by `resp12=sess.get('/friend_url', cookies=dict(cookies))` and see if it works?

Comment: I just posted print resp12.headers, should I post resp12.sth_else ?

Comment: Okay, I'll try that for the cookies, but I did it some time ago, and it is no longer needed thank's to the "session" stuff that I use : sess = requests.Session()

Comment: ah right, forget about that. but from the response headers, clearly your cookies expire right away once you're logged in. I think this is the problem

Comment: Same thing, provided I changed anything in the behavior of th stuff. because anyway, even without the cookie stuff, I was already logged on as my "credit" claim it.

Comment: Okay, I've just read about the delay; how to correct that ?

Comment: I may write down the cookies, and change the date by ten minutes... It would make me learn a lot about text processing...

Comment: Normally i just use requests object along with cookies, and alter the no-cache headers. But hey, have you tried `sess.get('another url not friends')` and see if you retrieve the content?

Comment: ther is somethig saying "path=/" in the headers; is it about what you were saying, and wouls it still be helpful to you ?

Comment: no it's not about that `path=/` because you're getting the `/home` response so that path made sense.

Comment: I request /panelboard, and it still goes to /home with almost no content, except the "credits" info.

Comment: Do you know if there is a mean to contact each other; here in France it's late and I will go to meal with my wife/girlfriend, but I would like to go on searching with you, or telling you my progress;
 David

Comment: um... without seeing the actual site, it's really hard to tell (but for sure session/cookie expires is one issue)

Comment: @dva2tise, don't worry we can chat later :)